# Nothing was returned from render when calling async function in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Adding console logs shows that I cam getting the data I want, so I know my calls are good, but I'm wondering if I'm using the async stuff wrong or just react in general.

All the examples I've found of this patter use `render()` but I don't think I need that in a functional component.

getCoinsByBuzz.js

```
import axios from "axios"

export async function GetCoinsByBuzz() {

     try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/graphql', {
            query: `query MyQuery {
            coinByBuzzChange {
              coinName
              symbol
              data
            }
}`
        });
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return await Promise.reject(err);
    }
};
```

lineChart.js  - ignore the data logic, I have some dummy data in there while I get things right so there are some other things wrong here.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import { GetCoinsByBuzz } from "../hooks/GetCoinsByBuzz"


ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend);

export const LineChart = () => {

    GetCoinsByBuzz().then((response) => {

        const fulldataset = response.data.data
        const dataset = fulldataset.coinByBuzzChange.slice(0, 10)

        const data = {};
        data.datasets = [];

        const colors = [
            'rgb(26, 188, 156)',
            'rgb(230, 126, 34)',
            'rgb(231, 76, 60)',
            'rgb(52, 152, 219)',
            'rgb(52, 73, 94)',
            'rgb(149, 165, 166)',
            'rgb(179, 55, 113)',
            'rgb(252, 66, 123)',
            'rgb(189, 197, 129)',
            'rgb(214, 162, 232)',
            ]

        var colorPicker = 0

        const labels = new Set()
        dataset.forEach(element => {

            const label = element.coinName;

            const elementDataSet = new Array()

            const keys = Object.keys(JSON.parse(element.data))

            const elementDataJson = JSON.parse(element.data)

            keys.forEach(key => {
                elementDataSet.push(elementDataJson[key].buzzScore)
            })

            data.datasets.push({

                data: [{x: 10, y: 20}, {x: 15, y: null}, {x: 20, y: 10}],
                borderColor: colors[colorPicker]
            });

            colorPicker += 1

        });

        console.log(data)

        return (
            <div style={{ width: '750px' }}>
            <Line data={data} />
            </div> 
        );
    })
};

export default LineChart;
```

index.js

```
import * as React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Seo from "../components/seo"
import {LineChart} from "../components/LineChart"

const IndexPage = () => (
  
  <Layout>
    <Seo title="Home" />
    <LineChart></LineChart>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  Could I please get some direction please?

I'm very new to react, and I'm just figuring it out as I go.

Comment: You have your return inside of a `.then`, you need to return stuff in the top level. Use `useState` and `useEffect` to make this work

Comment: Re edit. They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). And see the second duplicate question which is specifically about function components.